# Replace <text:s/> with whitespace

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I try to parse this xml-information:

```
<text:p >Lorem<text:s/>ipsum.</text:p>
```

Therefore I'm using XMLReader. Nearly everything is working as I need it. But the <text:s/>-element makes some trouble for me.
As I want to remove any formatting tags (i.e. bold) I'm using `expand()->textContent` to get just the text:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open("content.xml");
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'text:p') echo utf8_decode($reader->expand()->textContent);
}
```

In this case I would get 'Loremipsum.' instead of 'Lorem ipsum.'. How can I replace every <text:s/> with a whitespace.

**Update:**
I did it this way: `preg_replace("/<\\/?text:s(\\s+.*?>|>)/", " ", utf8_decode($reader->readInnerXML()))`

**Update:**

If I'm using DOMDocument for parsing, how do I have to change the syntax?

```
$reader = new DOMDocument();
$reader->load("zip://folder/".$file.".odt#content.xml");

while ($reader->read()){ 
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'text:h') { 
        if ($reader->getAttribute('text:outline-level')=="2") $html .= '<h2>'.$reader->expand()->textContent.'</h2>';
    }
    elseif ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'text:p') { 
        if ($reader->getAttribute('text:style-name')=="Standard") {
            $str = $reader->readInnerXML(); 
            // replace text:s-elements with " " at this point
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `$string = str_replace("<text:s/>", " ",$string);` or `$string = str_replace("<text:s/>", "\n",$string);`

Comment: `expand()->textContent` leads to a string without other tags. So the text:s-tag is already eliminated in the if-clause. That's my problem...

Comment: Then try `echo utf8_decode($reader->expand()->textContent) . " ";` or `echo utf8_decode($reader->expand()->textContent) . "\n";` - or put the `. " "` inside the closing bracket.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense to put a whitespace after the content. While using expand()->textContent the text:s-tag is already deleted - as it deletes every tag. With your snippet I would add a whitespace at the end of the already eliminated string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to output the `<text:p>` elements, but you want to output just text-nodes and the `<text:s>` element as just a space:

```
 $reader = new XMLReader();
 $result = $reader->open("content.xml");
 if (!$result) {
     throw new UnexpectedValueException('Could not open XML file for reading.');
 }

while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'text:s') {
        echo " "; // SPACE
    }
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::TEXT) {
        echo $reader->textContent;
    }
}
```

So it's more a problem with the processing logic and less a technical issue with **XMLReader**.

Some note on the character encoding I've left out in my example:

The conversion to Latin-1 you do (`utf8_decode`) should normally not be necessary if you deliver the output as UTF-8. See [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).

If it's necessary for your target output, it's most likely not necessary to take care of it at that place, see [ob_iconv_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-iconv-handler.php).

Comment: Thank you for the interesting answer. In the file, there are text:h and text:p elements, which I have to treat differently. In this question I described the part for the text:p-nodes. So I think I cannot use XMLREADER::TEXT only. And yes, I have some encoding problems: The ODT-file has characters like german umlauts, em dashes, turkish characters or ie. 'µ'. I tried to use utf8_decode, but I get sometimes '?'. It is a little bit strange, as some characters are converted correctly.

Comment: stick to utf-8, don't decode. and instead of **XMLReader** use **DOMDocument** to parse the file.

Comment: I've updated the post. Would like to try DOMDocument, but I have some problems with the syntax of that... Would be great if you can help.