# RegEx: Replacing text:s-tags

Tags: php, regex

I try to replace all variations of these tags with a whitespace:

```
<text:s></text:s>
<text:s/>
<text:s anyattributes/>
```

But `<text:span>` shouldn't be affected.

```
preg_replace("/<\\/?text:s(\\s+.*?>|>)/", " ", $string);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you duplicating your own question ? [Replace <text:s/> with whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685034/replace-texts-with-whitespace)

Comment: I thought that my solution was correct, but it wasn't. This problem is a regEx-Problem. The linked thread was about xml. Therefore I made a new question. Sorry, if that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and replace the match with a space.

```
<\/?text:s\b[^<>]*>
```

code would be,

```
preg_replace("~<\/?text:s\b[^<>]*>~", " ", $string);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY1lW8/3)

`\b` word boundary helps you to get the job done. Since `\b` matches between a word and a non-word character, the above regex won't match the string `<text:span>` because there isn't a word boundary exists between `s` and `p`